# Open cmd and run command from RDP ( BAT FILE RDP )

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, batch-file, cmd.exe

i am using bat file to connect multiple PC's , here is my code for example

```
@echo off
cmdkey /generic:10.38.19.79 /user:administrator /pass:testpass
cls
mstsc.exe /v:10.38.19.79


echo Done
exit
```

With this code i can login automaticaly in RDP , but i need after this to run the specified file in the same directory or open cmd and execute command.